# counting sort C code giving segmentation fault after submitting on codechef and works fine on my computer

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm doing a simple counting sort. I've tested with many test cases. Works fine on my computer but after submitting on code chef gives runtime error: segmentation fault. Someone please help me. I'm pasting my code here

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define i64 long long

int main(){
int n,i,t;
i64 *max=(i64 *)malloc(sizeof(i64)),*diff=(i64 *)malloc(sizeof(i64));
scanf("%d",&t);
while(t--){
    *max=-9999999999;
    *diff=9999999999;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    i64 A[n],B[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%llu",&A[i]);
        if(*max<A[i])
            *max=A[i];
        B[i]=0;
    }
    i64 k=*max;
    i64 C[k+1];
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<=k;i++) {
        C[i]=0;
    }
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        C[A[j]]=C[A[j]]+1;
        B[j]=0;
    }

    for(i=1;i<=k;i++) {
        C[i]=C[i]+C[i-1];
    }
    for(j=n-1;j>=0;j--){
        B[C[A[j]]-1]=A[j];
        C[A[j]]=C[A[j]]-1;
    }
    for(i=1;i<n;i++){
        if(*diff>B[i]-B[i-1])
            *diff=B[i]-B[i-1];
    }
    printf("%llu\n",*diff);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just curious, why are you dynamically allocating `max` and `diff`?

Comment: This is `C99`.. see if your codechef doesn't have some `C89` compiler.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: I tried using max and diff without pointers, it was printing some garbage values. Doing this solved the problem

Comment: The compiler used by code chef is gcc-4.3.2. Is it C99 or C89?
Mind explaining a bit about what the difference is?

Answer (score 0):

The obvious candidate is

```
i64 k=*max;
i64 C[k+1];
```

If `*max` is large, that declares an array that is likely far too large for the stack, in which case a segmentation fault is a typical outcome. If any number in the input is negative, that would be another likely cause for a segfault.

Comment: So, is counting sort not good for long long integers? Can you please give me a way out of this. I can use quick sort but linear time is always tempting
There are no negative numbers as per problem statement.

Comment: Counting sort is great if the number of items to sort is much larger than the range of numbers. If the number is much smaller than the range, it's bad (it's not really `O(count)`, it's `O(max(count,range))`, so if you want to sort 1000 items with min 0 and max 10^12, it's abysmal). For arrays of at most a few million items, the difference between `O(n)` and `O(n*log n)` is usually far outweighed by the constant factors. If you absolutely want an `O(n)` sort, try [Radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort), but I'd recommend quicksort or mergesort.